# MBR error at boot Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I tried to fix it with the DVD but without a result.

If the boot order is 1 DVD, 2 HDD it asks to boot from Dvd.

Comment: Did you check the boot order yet?

Comment: You can’t “merge” partitions. This is, at best, a custom-made action by partition managers that carries *extreme* risk. So, now that you probably destroyed your installation, you might as well reinstall Windows. Other than that, you could expand on your “tried to fix it” section with what exactly you tried.